# entity framework keep adding rows without any request

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a small project where I want to import some data to my db very quickly. For some objects like my import user, I prefer to cache the object to save some time on the queries. So I've implement the singleton pattern like this:

```
 public static class CacheHelper
 {
        static User _user; 
        public static User Modifier
        {
            get
            {
                if (_user == null)
                {
                    using (var db = new BerendsensDataContext())
                    {
                        _user = db.Users.First();
                    }
                }
                return _user;
            }
        }
   }
```

So whenever I need the user I just write CacheHelper.Modifier and I have the user object to add to my objects like this:

```
         db.Customers.Add(new Customer()
           {
                ModifyDate = DateTime.Now,
                Modifier = CacheHelper.Modifier,
            });
            db.SaveChanges();
```

This process will add a user on each run of my application:
[image]

I went through it step by step.
on the first request, it will take user with id:1 from the db and fills the static object as it should. then someone else asks for Modifier, it looks at the static object and returns the user with Id:1, but then it will create another row in the db and when someone ask for it, it will give user id:12

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where are you calling the `db.Customers.Add(new Customer() {` part?

Comment: @shreeshaadiga it is a console application. in main, I create an object of customer manager, then I call import inside that

Comment: can you share some code? Maybe every time you save a Customer object `Modifier = CacheHelper.Modifier` which has a `User` Object gets inserted again.

Comment: When you get the user, you wrap this code in "using" directive, which disposes db context and removes your User object from ChangeTracker, so referencing this entity in any DbContext will account this entity as newly created, so it needs to be inserted. You have to either reference it in change tracker, or set `Customer.ModifierId = Modifier.Id` which will correctly insert row with reference to your modifier.